# how to add a ssh directory in finder?

Tags: finder, ssh, remote-disc

I have a linux computer and I can access to it trough the terminal with the command:
`ssh account_name@123.117.140.61`

Now I am trying to access to the folders in that computer trough finder using the connect to server option.  I receive the following error `There was a problem connecting to the server`.

How can I solve?

Comment: What protocol are you trying to use when using “Connect to server”?

Comment: I do not have any options choose. I can only write the address  `smb://account_name@123.117.140.61/` I did not even find a place to insert the password.

Comment: What do you intend to use? smb or ssh?

Comment: `ssh` . I have tried also `ftps://account@ip/` but it does not work either.